# PHP - Remove Element If Not Logged In

Tags: php, authentication, content-management-system, backend

I'm using the same header.php and footer.php for php files on the backend of a CMS so when a user wants to login, they'll a part of that header.php that I don't want them to see as it's part of the backend e.g.

```
<section id="sidebar">
<p>Not to be seen</p>
</section>

<section id="content">
<p>Login here</p>
</section>
```

Is there a PHP function that if a user is logged in, can see the #sidebar and those who are not logged in will remove it. Using display: none; is pointless as it still visible if somebody was to remove that CSS style.

### Update:

I found out how to do it. The function was

```
<?php if(($user = Users::authed()) !== false): ?>
<section id="sidebar">
    <p>Not to be seen</p>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>

<section id="content">
    <p>Login here</p>
</section>
```

Thanks to those who answered!

Comment: How do you know if a user is logged in? Cookie? Session?

Comment: I thought it was session but I may be wrong. I'm knew to PHP.

Comment: Is this CMS written by yourself? Then you should know how to find out wether the user is logged in, or not. otherwise you should tell us, what CMS you are using.

Comment: @nischayn22 No, why do you ask?

Comment: @Polygnome Apologies, the CMS is called Anchor (http://anchorcms.com)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you login the user i.e. using cookies or sessions or something else.

The basic workflow will however be

```
if(user_logged_in())
echo "<section id=\"sidebar\">
<p>Not to be seen</p>
</section>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have to try this scenario with native session i hope it will work for you

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  <section id="sidebar">
  <p>Not to be seen</p>
  </section>
}else{
 <section id="content">
 <p>Login here</p>
 </section>
}
```

Comment: i told you try this with native session @JamieBrittain

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest form.

1. Once logged in populate session variable like `$_SESSION["UserID"]` with some user id or username
2. Modify your code like follows:

   <section id="sidebar">

   <p>Not to be seen</p>

   </section>

   <?php

   if ($_SESSION["UserID"]) {

   ?>

   <section id="content">

   <p>Login here</p>

   </section>

   <?php 
   } 
   ?>